# Correct table scaling

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

My code creates a scene for QGraphicsView that contains a QGraphicsProxyWidget inside of which is a QTableWidget. I have tried to scale the table and QGraphicsProxyWidget depending on the size of columns and rows, but I cannot achieve that the table always corresponds to the size of its contents and does not have scrolling, which hides rows or columns that simply do not fit.

```
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt
from PySide6.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap, QBrush
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsRectItem, QGraphicsTextItem, \
    QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QGraphicsProxyWidget, QStyledItemDelegate
import sys


class ImageDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ImageDelegate, self).__init__(parent)

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        pixmap = index.data(Qt.DecorationRole)
        if pixmap:
            rect = option.rect
            scaled_pixmap = pixmap.scaled(rect.width(), rect.height(), Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.SmoothTransformation)
            x = rect.x() + (rect.width() - scaled_pixmap.width()) / 2
            y = rect.y() + (rect.height() - scaled_pixmap.height()) / 2
            painter.drawPixmap(x, y, scaled_pixmap)
        else:
            super().paint(painter, option, index)


class Table(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, rows, columns):
        super().__init__(rows, columns)
        self.setItemDelegate(ImageDelegate(self))

        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)


        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

        for i in range(rows):
            for j in range(columns):
                if i == 0 and j == 0:  # Add an image to the first cell
                    item = QTableWidgetItem()
                    pixmap = QPixmap('D:\\User\\AaCePbBf.png')  # Replace with the path to your image
                    if not pixmap.isNull():  # Check if the pixmap was successfully created
                        item.setData(Qt.DecorationRole, pixmap)
                    self.setItem(i, j, item)
                else:
                    self.setItem(i, j, QTableWidgetItem(f"({j}, {i})"))

        total_width = sum([self.columnWidth(i) for i in range(self.columnCount())])
        total_height = sum([self.rowHeight(i) for i in range(self.rowCount())])

        # Set the total width and height
        self.setMinimumWidth(total_width)
        self.setMinimumHeight(total_height)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

scene = QGraphicsScene()

table = Table(10, 10)
proxy = QGraphicsProxyWidget()
proxy.setWidget(table)
proxy.setMinimumSize(table.minimumWidth(), table.minimumHeight())
scene.addItem(proxy)

view = QGraphicsView()
view.setScene(scene)
view.setSceneRect(0, 0, 5000, 5000)
view.show()

sys.exit(app.exec())
```

I know it's not normal to ask 2 questions, but is my mechanism for adding an image to a table cell OK? It seems to me that even small images lose a lot of quality due to image scaling.

Comment: [`columnWidth()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtableview.html#columnWidth) (just like `rowHeight()`) only returns the current width of the given column, cells don't resize themselves automatically to their contents unless told so, which happens by calling `setColumnWidth()` for specific column and width, or by means of `resizeColumnsToContents()` or proper header resize mode. Besides, the size computation is wrong: 1. it should consider the size hint of rows and columns (and you should specify a size hint for the image cell); 2. it doesn't take into account the headers and frame size.

Comment: Note that image scaling will always result in some level of quality degradation, which may be much more visible for pixel perfect source images (having straight lines and shapes) when the scaled size is *close* the original. Qt uses a bilinear transformation (for the `SmoothTransformation` flag), which is a good speed/quality compromise, but it certainly is not the best scaling algorithm (which is normally chosen depending on the image contents). May I ask why are you adding such a table to a graphics scene?

Comment: @musicamante And what other options do you know for loading and scaling an image? At the moment I'm not too constrained by resources and loading time, the main thing is quality.

Comment: Unfortunately, if you're dealing with images having pixel detailed shapes, almost any common scaling algorithm will give you distortions or artifacts when resized to very similar sizes. That's a fundamental limitation of digital signals (including digital images): scaling means resampling, and resampling to similar rates always results in artifacts (read more about [aliasing](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing)). For instance, a sequence of straight vertical or horizontal lines can result in *some* lines becoming blurred, while others may be shown as being as precise as the source image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt, QSize
from PySide6.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap, QBrush
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsRectItem, QGraphicsTextItem, \
    QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QGraphicsProxyWidget, QStyledItemDelegate
import sys


class ImageDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ImageDelegate, self).__init__(parent)

    def sizeHint(self, option, index):
        icon = index.data(Qt.DecorationRole)
        if icon:
            return QSize(128, 128)  # Set the size of the icon to 128x128 pixels
        else:
            return super().sizeHint(option, index)

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        icon = index.data(Qt.DecorationRole)
        if icon:
            rect = option.rect
            icon.paint(painter, rect, Qt.AlignCenter)
        else:
            super().paint(painter, option, index)


class Table(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, rows, columns):
        super().__init__(rows, columns)
        self.setItemDelegate(ImageDelegate(self))

        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

        for i in range(rows):
            for j in range(columns):
                if i == 0 and j == 0:  # Add an image to the first cell
                    item = QTableWidgetItem()
                    pixmap = QPixmap('D:\\User\\10101_gacksung_profile.png')  # Replace with the path to your image
                    if not pixmap.isNull():  # Check if the pixmap was successfully created
                        icon = QIcon(pixmap)
                        item.setData(Qt.DecorationRole, icon)
                    self.setItem(i, j, item)
                else:
                    self.setItem(i, j, QTableWidgetItem(f"({j}, {i})"))

        self.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.resizeRowsToContents()

        total_width = sum([self.columnWidth(i) for i in
                           range(self.columnCount())]) + self.verticalHeader().width() + 2 * self.frameWidth()
        total_height = sum([self.rowHeight(i) for i in
                            range(self.rowCount())]) + self.horizontalHeader().height() + 2 * self.frameWidth()

        self.setMinimumWidth(total_width)
        self.setMinimumHeight(total_height)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

scene = QGraphicsScene()

table = Table(15, 15)
proxy = QGraphicsProxyWidget()
proxy.setWidget(table)
scene.addItem(proxy)

view = QGraphicsView()
view.setScene(scene)
view.setSceneRect(0, 0, 5000, 5000)
view.show()

sys.exit(app.exec())
```

I was able to fix both problems although I'm not sure I did it correctly and in the best possible way.
What I changed:

1. Reworked the minimum table size calculation to take into account headers and frame size
2. changed the image additions to the QIcon using paint. (The image looks stretched if you set its original size using QSize)

If you have anything to add or suggest, please write.

Comment: You should also consider using [`setSizeHint()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtablewidgetitem.html#setSizeHint) of the item with the image using the pixmap size: by default, the delegate always adds some margins to the contents of the item (including its decoration), and since your delegate is drawing the pixmap using the *full* size of the rectangle, the resulting image will be scaled up by a few pixels.